# Hide a ckeditor field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have the following code. And I need to disable a f.cktext_area from ckeditor gem:

```
 <%= f.cktext_area "content", class: "js-globalize-attribute", 
   style: "display: none"  %>
```

But style option does not work with ckeditor and could not find any other way. Some help to disable or hide this component from options. Thanks!

Comment: You want to disable it or hide it? Why not use `f.textarea` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area) if you don't want CK editor?

Comment: This is because is used in a translated page using globalize gem, so there are cktext_areas that does not show until you active the language.

Comment: text_area is not a editor(with styles) component

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the editor is initialized after loading, so your `display: none` is replaced. you have to work with it on javascript, and hide it after initialized, or don't init at all the plugin on that page.

another option, simpler is to just put the input in a div with the desired style

```
<div style="display: none">
<%= f.cktext_area "content", class: "js-globalize-attribute" %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already try the div but does not work. Yes the only way is to hide with javascript after initialized the page. Or maybe work with text_area and initialize the ckeditor after load the page. My specific question was if there is a way to hide the ckeditr component from options.

Comment: I tested the div on local and it worked without problems. but I don't think so, if you are using the cktext_area, is not logical to hide it by options. maybe use text_area is the best for your use case